# Angular Form Reactive Approach - Disable Submission via Enter Key (Ionic App)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've searched the web extensively for this but cannot find a solution. I have an Ionic app with a page that has a reactive Angular form. I'm only testing on the browser right now, and when I hit enter on that page, it activates my `onSubmit()` method.

Is it possible to disable the enter key from submitting the form?

```
<form [formGroup]="movieListForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<form (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()"></form>
```